# Binding collection of objects on a tooltip

Tags: wpf, binding, collections, tooltip, stackpanel

Can someone tell me how to bind the tooltip of a `StackPanel` with its children?

Here's some code I used:

```
<StackPanel>
... (some UI like grid, textblock, border, ...)
<StackPanel.ToolTip>
 <ToolTip Placement="RelativePoint" Padding="0" HasDropShadow="False">
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel, AncestorLevel=3}, Path=Children}"
                 Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel, AncestorLevel=3}, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                 Height="11">
   </ItemsControl>
  </ToolTip>
</StackPanel.ToolTip>
<StackPanel>
```

I first tried with `VisualBrush` that was binded on a `ToolTip`, but this shows only the non-hidden controls, so when a child was hidden (invisible for the eye, not for the PC) in the `StackPanel`, then that child was also invisible in the `ToolTip`.

Also want to say that the binding with ActualWidth works. Now i have a tooltip that has the right measures, but there is no content in it (it's just a filled white space rectangle).

Someone please help me?? :)

FYI, what i want is the same like you bind on the Content property of a Textblock with his tooltip. The only difference is that i want to bind on a collection of objects instead of a string value.

Comment: Can't you put the exact same StackPanel as the parent ?

Comment: you mean instead of an ItemControl? Please tell me how to bind on the Children property because that property is read-only --'  ...

Comment: You can google for "WPF binding to Children". I know I've binded to Children property using attached property. I can't find link right now though. But with a little bit of googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably caused by the fact the ToolTip is not part of the StackPanel's visual tree.

Therefore the StackPanel is not an Ancestor of the ToolTip -> hence why the RelativeSource binding wont work.

Answer (score 0):

In **WPF** you are supposed to use **MVVM**, because it will allow you to bind always to data, instead of other controls. You have to think about **WPF controls** as **data visualizers**, not as data containers.

So, if you are using MVVM, just bind the Tooltip ItemsControl to your (observable?)collection of items.

Comment: i am using MVVM. whats your point with that text of yours..? copy pasted from another site or what..?

Comment: The point is that you are trying to bind the ItemsControl.ItemsSource to the StackPanel items. Why? As said, bind it to your MVVM collection.